# How do you figure out which frequency to contact approach on for a class bravo transition?

Tags: air-traffic-control, radio-communications, airspace, frequency

I'm about 20 hours into my PPL, so maybe I just haven't gotten to this part yet.

Suppose I'm flying KFCM to KRNH and I want to request clearance across the bravo. How do I figure out which approach frequency to contact KMSP on?

From [liveatc.net](https://www.liveatc.net/search/?icao=KMSP), it looks like approach is 121.2 or 126.5 (for low altitude). At [skyvector](https://skyvector.com/airport/MSP/Minneapolis-St-Paul-International-Wold-Chamberlain-Airport), 121.2 and 126.5 are listed under Class B. From the [Chart Supplements](https://www.aopa.org/ustprocs/20210325/chart/msp_chart_supplement.pdf) - neither of those frequencies appear. Am I just looking at the wrong information?

I found a similar case for KPBI where the approach frequency (124.6) doesn't show up on the chart supplemental.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The example KFCM to KRNH starts under the Class B shelf, in this case you check [**KFCM**'s chart supplement](https://skyvector.com/airport/FCM/Flying-Cloud-Airport), and it says, "MINNEAPOLIS APP/DEP CON 134.7":

> [image]

Which also agrees with the sectional *(shown below).*

Zoom out in the sectional, and you'll note different frequencies to the NW and NE of the Class B, so if you're transitioning through, the frequency will depend on which direction you're coming from.

> [image]
> Minneapolis-St Paul TAC chart via [skyvector.com](https://skyvector.com/?ll=44.55216141380273,-93.71607280516234&chart=117&zoom=4)

Definitely don't use liveatc for frequencies, as that's a hobbyist site.

If you're departing during the tower's operating hours, requesting flight following would be more practical. Also, see related:

- [On a chart, how can I find the frequency for flight following?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1456/14897)
- [Where is flight following available?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/79020/14897)
- [Why did the tower at a Class D airport not set me up with flight following on the ground?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/70259/14897)
- [Is a VFR flight following request implied when talking to tower and advising them of your intended airport?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/52442/14897)
- [How do I contact Flight Service while in flight?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1473/14897)

Comment: +1 for answering the question asked although for practical purposes you might also mention flight following here. If you're on it then you don't have to worry about searching for frequencies because you'll always be talking to ATC.

Comment: @Pondlife: done, thanks :)

Comment: If I were flying the opposite way (KRNH-KFCM), how would I make that request if I had flight following already?

Technically, I could avoid the entire Bravo space, but if I wanted to request a transition through the Bravo and over the airport would I put that request into FSS or after contacting approach?

Comment: @Shuo: After contacting approach, also see: [Where does one request a VFR transition route through class B?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/67780/14897)